# Generate link to Google Analytics dashboard from view id and tracking code

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I have Google Analytic's `Tracking ID` and `View id` for a bunch of my web properties. Now I want to generate a link to the GA dashboard for each property.

Let's say my tracking ID is `UA-88827517-1` and my view ID is `135789866`. When I go to the dashboard, the url is:

https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#report/defaultid/a88827517w131876043p135789866/

Obviously they made this magic identifier at the end from parts of my tracking id (the `a` part) and the view id (the `p` part). But what is the number after `w`?

How do I get this number? Can I generate this link without it?

It seems like my property ID and view ID should be enough to get into the dashboard.

Comment: Oh, cool! Thanks. My search skills have failed me.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses it internally as a property ID (as a substitute for UA-XXXXX-XX).

Comment: Ok, so how do I get it? Or generate link without it?

Comment: You call [Account Summaries list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list)